# LibGDX Animation Java to Kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin, animation, libgdx

I am trying to convert this LibGDX example on Animation using a sprite sheet from Java to Kotlin

Here is the link to the Java code snippet:
https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/2D-Animation

Here is my Kotlin code:

```
 // load the sprite sheet as a texture
    idleSheet = Texture("raw/Skeleton-Idle.png".toInternalFile())
    idleFrames = Array<TextureRegion>(true, FRAME_ROWS*FRAME_COLS)

    // use split method to create 2d array of texture regions
    // sprite sheet contains frames of equal size & alignment
    var temp = TextureRegion.split(
        idleSheet,
        idleSheet.width / FRAME_COLS,
        idleSheet.height / FRAME_ROWS
    )

    var index = 1
    for (i in 1..FRAME_ROWS) {
        for (j in 1..FRAME_COLS) {
             idleFrames[index] = temp[i][j]
            index ++
        }
    }
    // initialise animation with frame interval & array of frames
    idleAnimation = Animation(0.05f,idleFrames)
```

The problem seems to be `Index 1 out of bounds for length 1` in line `idleFrames[index] = temp[i][j]` - I am doing something very basic wrong with Kotlin Arrays but can't seem to fix it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply - I actually moved onto TextureAtlases a while ago after coming to a road block here. Just came back to see if i could solve this puzzle anyway

Comment: Just tried your solution - `index can't be >= size: 0 >= 0` is the new error - points to the same line `idleFrames[index] = temp[i][j]`

Comment: Oh, I just realized you're using LibGDX's Array class, not Kotlin's array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `..` is end *inclusive*. until is end *exclusive*.
2. Arrays start at index 0, not 1. So use `i in 0 until FRAME_ROWS`, for example.
3. The libGDX Array class behaves a lot like a List. You can't directly assign values to indices that haven't been filled yet. So instead of `idleFrames[index] = temp[i][j]`, use `idleFrames.add(temp[i][j])` and you can get rid of the `index` variable entirely.

Comment: Thanks, got to remember the differences between the two types Array! I'll go back to TextureAtlases now

Comment: One way to help with this is to create a typealias for the libGDX Array, and call it something like GdxArray.